# Count elements by id

Tags: javascript, count, element

I need to be able to set a var with the number of open orders on a website I use.

Warning:
This site, for some reason, uses the same ids over and over again per order, but as this is not my site, I can not change that.

code of my current orderlist:

```
<div id="orderlist">
<label id="l61">05/19/2014 08:57:34</label>
<label id="l62">0.00066000</label>
<label id="l63">Buy</label>
<label id="l64">6</label>
<label id="l64">6</label>
<label id="l62">0.00396000</label>
<label id="l65" onclick="cancelOrder(346046);">Cancel</label>
<div id="b1"></div>
<label id="l61">05/19/2014 03:08:35</label>
<label id="l62">0.00078000</label>
<label id="l63">Sell</label>
<label id="l64">2</label>
<label id="l64">1</label>
<label id="l62">0.00078000</label>
<label id="l65" onclick="cancelOrder(38493);">Cancel</label>
<div id="b1"></div>
<label id="l61">05/19/2014 03:12:08</label>
<label id="l62">0.00076000</label>
<label id="l63">Sell</label>
<label id="l64">14</label>
<label id="l64">14</label>
<label id="l62">0.01064000</label>
<label id="l65" onclick="cancelOrder(38495);">Cancel</label>
<div id="b1"></div>
<label id="l61">05/19/2014 03:13:49</label>
<label id="l62">0.00077000</label>
<label id="l63">Sell</label>
<label id="l64">15</label>
<label id="l64">15</label>
<label id="l62">0.01155000</label>
<label id="l65" onclick="cancelOrder(38497);">Cancel</label>
<div id="b1"></div> </div>
</div>
```

What I'd need to do basically, is count the number of ids "l65". Or another id, it doesn't matter, they are all used each time a new order is added.

What would be the easiest way to do this? I'd need this number in a var, so that I can perform functions based on that number.

Comment: An HTML id MUST be unique. Use a `class` if you want to keep the current structure

Comment: In my experience, using same id more than once in a html document, is asking for trouble.

Comment: As stated, I do not run that site, I just want to count how many orders I have on that site. I can not change anything on their end...

Comment: $("label[id^=l65]").length  will do the trick, you just need to pass the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest trick :

```
   $("label[id^=l65]").length  // will directly give you the count
```

Traditional :

```
 $("label").each(function() {
       var totalId = countId(this.id);
       console.log(this.id + " : "+totalId); // this will alert l65 : count of 165
    });
```

Reusable function: pass id which is 165

```
function countId(id) {
   var counter = 0;
   $("label").each(function() {
     if(this.id==id) {
        counter+=1;
      } 
   });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can do this It will not match exect id but the id starts with l61

```
 $('[id^=l61]').length
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**html:**

```
<div id="orderlist">
<label id="l61">05/19/2014 08:57:34</label>
<label id="l62">0.00066000</label>
<label id="l63">Buy</label>
<label id="l64">6</label>
<label id="l64">6</label>
<label id="l62">0.00396000</label>
<label id="l65" onclick="cancelOrder(346046);">Cancel</label>
<div id="b1"></div>
<label id="l61">05/19/2014 03:08:35</label>
<label id="l62">0.00078000</label>
<label id="l63">Sell</label>
<label id="l64">2</label>
<label id="l64">1</label>
<label id="l62">0.00078000</label>
<label id="l65" onclick="cancelOrder(38493);">Cancel</label>
<div id="b1"></div>
<label id="l61">05/19/2014 03:12:08</label>
<label id="l62">0.00076000</label>
<label id="l63">Sell</label>
<label id="l64">14</label>
<label id="l64">14</label>
<label id="l62">0.01064000</label>
<label id="l65" onclick="cancelOrder(38495);">Cancel</label>
<div id="b1"></div>
<label id="l61">05/19/2014 03:13:49</label>
<label id="l62">0.00077000</label>
<label id="l63">Sell</label>
<label id="l64">15</label>
<label id="l64">15</label>
<label id="l62">0.01155000</label>
<label id="l65" onclick="cancelOrder(38497);">Cancel</label>
<div id="b1"></div> </div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
$(function(){
    var i=0;
    $("label").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("id") == "l65")
          i++;
    });
    console.log(i);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2sG9/)

This example counts all labels which id's are equal to lbl65.

Comment: Please explain your answers. Code dumps are bad answers and will be downvoted